# How to Create One Instance per Bookmark?

Tags: persistence, workflow-foundation-4, sqlworkflowpersistencese

### Background:

We currently use WF 4 and the SQL Workflow Instance Store to persist our workflows at each bookmark. The first time a workflow is persisted, a new record is created in the table "System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstancesTable". On each subsequent persist, existing records are deleted and a new record inserted.

### Question:

How could you modify this behavior so that on each subsequent persist, a **new** record would be created in the instances table?

### Notes:

You can create a custom instance store, but it is "non-trivial" to do so. Is there a way you could use the System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStore class, but customize this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The InstancesTable contains a record per workflow instance so having multiple records there for the same workflow instance would be very confusing at the very least.

It kind of sounds like you are trying to use the InstancesTable for tracking. If that is the case you should take a look at creating a [TrackingParticipant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.trackingparticipant.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The Tracking Participant is similar, but we've resolved the problem with our own database tables. After each persist, we record all the data from the InstancesTable into our own table along with our record's key and it's status. That way capture a snapshot of the persisted workflow at each step.